# String macro expansion with arguments. C

Tags: c, string, macros

This problem is driving me crazy. For meta-programming reasons I need to expand a variadic macro into a string.

My code is something like this:

```
#define macro(A, B) "Lorem "#A" ipsum "#B

void main () {
    printf (macro(1, 2));
}
```

So this will print out: Lorem 1 ipsum 2.

The thing is I need to sum a variable with an integer, so I tried the following:

```
#define macro(A, B) "Lorem "#A" ipsum "#B

void main () {
    int x = 1;
    printf (macro(x+1, 2));
}
```

And:

```
#define macro(A, C, B) "Lorem "#(A+C)" ipsum "#B

void main () {
    int x = 1;
    printf (macro(1, x, 2));
}
```

But none of this works for me, is it impossible? Or maybe there's a way to do it.

I can't just use `printf` with arguments, what I need is to expand the macro into the string.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get "Lorem 2 ipsum 2" then it is impossible, at least if don't change your design.

x is a variable, and x+1 is a runtime construct. No macro is going to make a runtime number to a static string.

Comment: Is there any way I can substitute that macro with an inline function?

Comment: I won't bother to write an inline function. Because a normal function will do. If you don't change the invocation pattern, the function may have reentrant problems though.